# Direct approach to set values to a column after a mathematical operation on it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

it is my first question on StackOverflow, so I will try to be as clear as possible. I am working with Sql-Server 2008.

I have a table (MyTable) which contains a few Customers. The fun fact is that each customer could be labeled with more than one IDCustomer, namely:

```
IdCustomer   Name       Surname           Nationality
   12         John         Monroe           IR
   11         Michael      Jackson          US
   18         Jordi        Alba             ES
   20         Harrison     Ford             US
   3          Harrison     Ford             US
   8          Jordi        Alba             ES
   45         Jordi        Alba             ES
   1          John        Monroe            IR  
   8          John        Monroe            IR
   5          Michael     Jackson           US
```

I have two tasks:

- for each distinct Customer (Name and Surname), keep only the record with the minimum IDCustomer
- Then, the IDCustomer must be set to 1, due to privacy reason

The first point is easily done:

```
select 
  min(IDCustomer),
  Name,    
  Surname,
  Nationality
  from MyTable
    group by
     Name,
     Surname,
     Nationality
```

Coming to the second task, I would like to write something like

```
select 
 min(IDCustomer)=1
...
```

because I know that

```
select
IDCustomer=1
....
```

will actually print all the IDCustomer values equal to 1.

My take doesn't work. However, after some efforts I was able to do the second task using a join with a subquery:

```
select 
     MT1.Desiredvalue, --which will be 1
     MT.Name,
     MT.Surname, 
     MT.Nationality
 from MyTable as MT

 inner join (
       select 
     MIN(IDCustomer), 
     DesiredValue=1 
     from MyTable
     group by 
     Name,
     Surname,
     Nationality
    ) as MT1
```

I would like to ask you whether it is possible to do the second task by using a direct approach (without subqueries) like my first take: min(IDCUstomer)=1.

I am asking this, because here I have provided a simplified version of my real problem. Dealing with my real table, I would prefer to avoid using subqueries if a direct approach, which I am currently missing, is available.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side-Note: why the customers don't have their own table? Storing redundant names (for each country) is crying out for refactoring. This should definitely be two tables.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the database I am working with doesn't have a Customer table. Every time a Customer asks for something online, he will be recorded in MyTable with an other IDCustomer. I know this is weird but this is how the database is organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete all customers for which exists a record that has smaller id:

```
delete c
from Customers c
where 1=1
    and exists (
        select
             1
        from Customers x
        where 1=1
            and x.Name=c.Name
            and x.Surname=c.Surname
            and x.IdCustomer < c.Customer
    )
```

Then you can set the rest to 1:
`update Customers set IdCustomer=1`

Also make sure that there are no multiple records for the same customer with id=1.

EDIT: 
If you only want to select the records without modifying them:

```
select 
     IDCustomer=1,
     c.Name,
     c.Surname, 
     c.Nationality
from Customers c
where 1=1
    and not exists (
        select
             1
        from Customers x
        where 1=1
            and x.Name=c.Name
            and x.Surname=c.Surname
            and x.IdCustomer < c.Customer
    )
```

Still there may be some doubled records with IDCustomer=1.

Comment: Thank you Adam for your answer, still I am not allowed to delete records from the db.

Comment: @SCanova Please see the edit - it looked like you wanted to modify the table.